# How do I perform an `around` or `aroundEach` with mocha?

Tags: callback, mocha.js

Mocha provides `before`, `beforeEach`, `after`, and `afterEach`.  I'm looking for something like `around` or `aroundEach`, but I can't find anything in the mocha docs about it.

My use case is that I'd like to wrap each test in a DB transaction, performing a rollback after each one is run.  I envision doing something like this:

```
aroundEach(function (testRunner, done) {
  sequelize.transaction().next(function (t) {
    testRunner();
    t.rollback().done(done);
  });
});
```

As an alternative/workaround, something like this exists as an option (although it feels less clean):

```
beforeEach(function (done) {
  sequelize.transaction().next((t) => {
    this.transaction = t;
    done();
  });
});

afterEach(function (done) {
  this.transaction.rollback().done(done);
});
```

Comment: @Louis I updated the question with an example.

Comment: Your alternative is about as good as it gets. However, I would not set a `transaction` field on Mocha's object. I would instead use a `transaction` variable in the closure created by the anonymous function passed to the closest `describe` call. You never know when the Mocha devs will decide that their object needs a `transaction` field for some reason.

Comment: FWIW mocha shows examples of setting variables on `this` context, e.g.: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Shared-Behaviours